# How to correctly display data from the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How to correctly display data from the mysql database but through the ID number. The ID number is entered on the INPUT(Edit) field in the field. Connection to the database works.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="id">
  <input type="submit" value"enter">
</form>  
   <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <td>id</td>
       <td>First Name</td>
       <td>Last Name</td>
     </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>    
<?php
require_once('conect.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];


$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id  ORDER BY id DESC ");
$result->execute();
$results = $result->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $index => $row)
{
?>          
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['FirstName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['LastName']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>

</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: What is the problem with current version of the code? I suppose `}` after query breaks your code.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute on the submit button is `submit` not `Submit`

Should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Also you should be using prepared statements. Bind the id variable to placeholder.